# Teensy 3.6 programming DAC

Tags: firmware, teensy

I'm trying to code the DACs in the Teensy 3.6 to a synthesizer.

The problem is that when I write in any of the registers to control the DAC module, the Teensy just stops responding!

Does anyone know if it is needed to initialize something before accessing the registers?

The basic code is below:

```
void setDACPos(byte pos){
   DAC0_C2 = (pos << 4 )| 15 ;
}
generateDacBuffer();
void setup() {

  DAC0_DAT0L = 0;
  Serial.println("asdasd");
  generateDacBuffer();
  setDACPos(0);
  DAC0_C1 = 1 | 1 <<6;
  DAC0_C0 = 1<<6 | 1 << 5 |  1 << 4;
}

int counter = 0;

void loop() {

  setDACPos(counter); // selects the value to output from the buffer at counter 
       position
  counter++;
  if(counter == 16){
    counter = 0;
  }

  delay (1000);
}

 void generateDacBuffer(){

  short deltaValue = 100;
  short startValue= 200;


  short* regs =(short*) 0x400CC000; // adress to the first buffer register = 
    DAC0_DAT0L 
  // also craches if i use variable  DAC0_DAT0L 

  short value = startValue; 
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){

    // crashes below
    *regs = holder;// also craches if i use variable  DAC0_DAT0L 

    value += deltaValue;
    regs++;
  } 

}
```

Comment: yes, somebody knows .... perhaps you could ask a technical question that is related to electronics instead

Comment: Is this the actual code? I don't think this compiles... You call `generateBuffer` in the setup routine, but the function is called `generateDACBuffer` in the code... What is `setDACPos`?

Comment: generateBuffer was a gramatic error and setDACpos(pos), tell the processor what position of the DACbuffer[0..15] to output , witch is generated with generateDACBuffer().